# Wrong colors on rendered video

Tags: color

I rendered my animation using eevee and video has wrong colors. If I render image it has correct colors exactly how they appear in viewport in preview mode. Perhaps there are video settings I don't know about?

Rendered video has color shift to yellow while original has red colors.

[image]

Color management settings:

[image]

Comment: What if you set *Sequencer*'s sRGB mode also to Raw?

Comment: Nope, video still has this awful yellowish tint

Comment: Might be video codec issue. Try exporting with AVI Raw or h.264+PNG codec

Comment: It has correct colors when I use Avi raw or FFmpeg format with png or ffmpeg #1 codecs. Anything else, vp9, h264, mpeg etc - makes colors yellowish. I also noticed when I convert avi raw in other software with vp9 or h264 it breaks colors. Only color correction in compositing somehow fixes that yellow tint. I searched a bit and I guess it's RGB and YUV color space issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After hours of research and trial I managed to get colors right. According [to this topic](https://developer.blender.org/T52697) on blender dev tracker blender renders video with BT601 conversion in YUV colorspace. That's why I had correct colors with RGB colorspace codecs (avi raw, FFmpeg codec #1 and png) and wrong colors with codecs using YUV colorspace (h264,vp9). BT601 conversion is used on SD videos, while BT709 is used on HD videos (my video has 4k resolution). So I figured a workaround:

1. Render video in blender in any lossless format that uses RGB color space (like AVI RAW, FFmpeg codec #1, png).
2. Use FFmpeg CLI to compress the raw video with any other codec, like h264 or vp9 using following parametr `-vf colormatrix=bt601:bt709`.

**Here is an example of covertion from raw avi to webm with color conversion correction:**

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v libvpx-vp9 -lossless 1 -vf colormatrix=bt601:bt709 output.webm
```

As you can see below, colors are almost identical (input on left, output on right). Output has slightly brighter color, but you won't notice it unless you are on really good IPS monitor.

[image]