# How to get video renders (FFmpeg) to be exact the same colour as still renders (e.g., png)?

Tags: rendering, animation

My question is [based on this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137548/wrong-colors-on-rendered-video).

I've gone through it all, but really don't know if I can be bothered to do this for every render! Have you found any shortcuts lately?

Comment: What display hardware?

Comment: Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting and is considered rude.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I made some suggested edits to the post.

Comment: @ComputerScientist Thanks

Comment: What settings are you using for color management? How are you evaluating the difference? What software are you using to play video? What happens when you load the rendered image in blender and compared to the rendered layers? What codec are you using to render?